# Flutter: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, crashlytics

From Crashlytics in Firebase I get this error in my Flutter app:

> FlutterJNI.java – line 116
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.loadLibrary

or

> FlutterJNI.java – line 1230
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterJNI.ensureRunningOnMainThread

apparently, a solution is to add this in settings.gradle:

```
gradle.beforeProject({ project->
    project.setProperty("target-platform", "android-arm")
})
```

But the problem is that I will remove support for all of these devices (some of them bought my app):

[image]

Is that the only solution?

Comment: Hi even my released application also having same issue. Any solution you found?

Comment: not yet, sorry.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Any news? @Dani

Comment: nothing at all.

Comment: I face same error,
i used "flutter build appbundle --split-debug-info" when i built aab,
did you do it?

Comment: no, I always ran flutter build appbundle --release

Comment: Firebase is reporting the same issue.

Comment: I need solution for this problem. here the error also happens. it's boring.

Answer (score 4):

This is a known issue tracked in this [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/83596). The error is commonly caused by attempting to run Flutter in x86 platform even though Flutter has yet to have [support for x86](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#what-are-the-supported-target-architectures). If the x86 devices has support for ARM emulation, then it should run without issues.